# iFrame performance issue

Tags: html, iframe, highcharts

I've got 4 html files that contain 1 highchart.  I'm using iFrame's to show each one on a webpage but I'm noticing some performance lag.  Is there a way to optimize an iFrame or is there a more performance friendly alternative?

Comment: Please explain your question with still more explanation, what performance you  lagging and why you have to show in iframe

Comment: The iframe load content from source, so many you have a lag with loading these file?